# grep -o: Keep input line format

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

```
$ echo "abca\ndeaf" | grep -o a  
a
a
a
```

I am looking for the output:

```
aa
a
```

Or perhaps

```
a a
a
```

or even

```
a<TAB>a
a
```

(this is a very very simplified example)

I just want it not to throw away the line grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to use `perl`:

```
$ echo $'abca\ndeaf' | perl -ne '@m = /a/g; print "@m\n"'
a a
a
```

Comment: I think this is closest to what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `sed` by removing any character that isn't `a`:

```
echo "abca\ndeaf" | sed 's/[^a]//g' 
aa
a
```

It can't be done with `grep` alone.

Comment: How to do this when my `a` is actually some regex like `<strong>.*?</strong>`?

Comment: By using a proper HTML parser.

Answer (score 3):

@sudo_O's answer shows how to do this with single-character strings. The difficulty level is raised if you want to match longer strings.

One way to do it is by parsing the output of `grep -n -o`, like so:

```bsh
$ cat mgrep
#!/bin/bash

# Print each match along with its line number.
grep -no "$@" | {
    matches=()  # An array of matches to be printed when the line number changes.
    lastLine=   # Keep track of the current and previous line numbers.

    # Read the matches, with `:' as the separator.
    while IFS=: read line match; do
        # If this is the same line number as the previous match, add this one to
        # the list.
        if [[ $line = $lastLine ]]; then
            matches+=("$match")

        # Otherwise, print out the list of matches we've accumulated and start
        # over.
        else
            (( ${#matches[@]} )) && echo "${matches[@]}"
            matches=("$match")
        fi

        lastLine=$line
    done

    # Print any remaining matches.
    (( ${#matches[@]} )) && echo "${matches[@]}"
}
```

Example usage:

```bsh
$ echo $'abca\ndeaf' | ./mgrep a
a a
a
$ echo $'foo bar foo\nbaz\ni like food' | ./mgrep foo
foo foo
foo
```

Comment: Bringing out the big guns with bash, i see (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Based off John Kugelman's solution, this one works with one input file and [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk)

```
grep -on abc file.txt | awk -v RS='[[:digit:]]+:' 'NF{$1=$1; print}'
```